# Stop cordova cli reverting build.gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

This one sounds a little bit weird!

I'm building an app with cordova, and I'm trying to implement firebase. I'm receiving the following error whenever I try to build

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
>
> For input string: "11+"

I've had a look on stack overflow and the fix is to remove the `+` from the `build.gradle` dependencies. I remove it and then build through android studio which works great, but whenever I try to build via cli using `cordova build android`, it reverts the `build.gradle` and adds the `+` back on and the build fails.

I need able to build via `Cordova build android` because if I don't build the application again via the cli, my changes to the code are not recognized!?

It's almost like every time I make a change, I have to run the build for the code changes to be recognized.

How can I build via `cordova build android` without it adding the `+` back into the `build.grade`?

Answer (score 3):

In a Cordova Android project, any files (including `build.gradle`) inside the `platforms/android/` directory are considered volatile and should not be manually edited. In fact if you run `cordova platform rm android` the entire `platforms/android/` directory will be deleted. The `build.gradle` file is dynamically recreated every time the `cordova prepare` lifecycle event takes place using a template from `cordova-android` and then is dynamically modified as Cordova plugins, etc. are processed.
So whatever solution you choose needs to work with the Cordova build lifecycle.

One option to is to use 3rd-party plugins to override the library versions specified by other Cordova plugins in order to align them and prevent such build failures, for example:

- [cordova-play-services-version-adapter](https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-play-services-version-adapter/)
- [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release)
- [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release)
- [cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release)